# Laplace's equation in presence of a dipole

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, dielectric

I know that in classical electrodynamics we're dealing with stuff macroscopically, so I can pretend that some volume of space is empty of charge when it's actually full of matter consisting of charged particles, and I can apply laplace's eauation safely and solve it for the potential in that region, given appropriate boundary conditions. But say I have a dielectric that has inside of it a dipole of free charge, can I still apply laplace's equation because the separation between the positive and negative charges is small and carry on with the that macroscopic logic ? Or is it not okay to apply Laplace's equation in such  a case and I should use the superposition principle in the process(superposing the potential of the dipole on the potential of the induced surface charge, and use laplace's equation for the potential of the induced surface charge alone)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply Laplace's equation alone. As you've stated, there is a non-zero free charge density in the region of interest:

$$\rho = -\vec{p}\cdot\nabla\delta(\vec{x}) \space \space\space\text{(A point dipole)}.$$

This result is derived in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/384485/what-is-the-charge-density-of-a-pure-electric-dipole) stack exchange post.

It is good to note, perhaps, that a point dipole is not equivalent to a positive charge directly on top of a negative charge. It is the limit of $p = qd$ as $d \rightarrow 0, q \rightarrow \infty$ (q is taken to such a limit to keep the dipole moment p constant).