# Can a point charge be asymmetric?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, multipole-expansion, point-particles

The derivation of Coulombs law from Maxwell's first equation for a point charge assumes that the field is symmetric along a sphere. What happens if this assumption is removed? Could there be other ways to distribute the charge on a point?

According to Griffiths, the charge density is described by the Dirac delta function. Is there an asymmetric equivalent?

Comment: To first order, no. You can account for higher-order asymmetries, though. If you continue reading Griffiths, he covers it when discussing the multipole expansion.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've read through the multipole expansion and I've never really though of perfect dipoles like that. This is very interesting.  So a perfect dipole is represented using a second order Dirac delta.

Comment: But keep in mind, that dipole or multipole expansions are not point charge models. By definition point charge has no dimensions and hence symmetry/asymmetry concepts does not apply here for $0D$ object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to write down the charge distribution for an infinitesimally small dipole. This was done here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/384501

For example, a point electric dipole located at the origin, whose dipole moment points along the positive z-axis, would have the charge distribution

$$ \rho(x, y, z) = -p\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta'(z) $$

where $p$ is the magnitude of the dipole moment, and $\delta'$ is the **distributional derivative** of the Dirac delta distribution. As a quick sanity check for this, we can try to compute the scalar potential at a point along the positive z-axis using Coulomb's law:

\begin{align} \varphi(z) &= -\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\delta'(z')}{z - z'} \, \mathrm{d}z' \\
&= \frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(z')\frac{1}{(z-z')^2} \, \mathrm{d}z' \\
&= \frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left[ \frac{1}{(z-z')^2} \right]_{z'=0} \\
&= \frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0 z^2}
\end{align}

Note that in order to derive the second line from the first, we used integration by parts to "transfer" the derivative from the delta distribution to the $1/(z-z')$ part. This resulted in a sign change and a boundary term that vanishes. The final result is exactly what we expect to find.

Similarly, we can dream of infinitesimal quadrupoles (which would have a second derivative of the Dirac delta) and higher-order multipoles.

**However, the term "point charge" always means a pure monopole** (i.e., it's spherically symmetric). Infinitesimal dipoles and so on are simply not *called* point charges, but they can exist. In fact, the electron is predicted to have a [nonzero dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_electric_dipole_moment) (in addition to its monopole moment, of course) by the Standard Model, though it's below current detection thresholds.